# Repeating a for loop in R X times and saving each value in a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I have the below code which is a function that repeats a t-test 100x to produce a needed power value from randomize sample groups (grp1 and grp2). What I want to do is repeat this function X number of times (the X is a user inputted value) and capture the value (in this case pwr) each time in a vector. I've played with the repeat and lapply functions, but getting either the same value repeated or nothing at all. Could someone help point me in a direction to get what I want done?

```
fun <- function(n1, n2, mu1, mu2, sig1, sig2, reps){
  grp1 <- matrix(rnorm(reps*n1, mu1, sig1), nrow = n1, ncol = reps) # Generate random group 1
  grp2 <- matrix(rnorm(reps*n2, mu2, sig2), nrow = n2, ncol = reps) # Generate random group 2
  pvals <- NULL
  for(i in 1:reps){
    pvals[i] <- t.test(grp1[,i], grp2[,i])$p.value
  }
  pwr <- sum(pvals < 0.05)/reps
  print(pwr)
}
```

Example Answer after running above code:

```
fun(20,30,25,32,15,20,100)
[1] 0.24 # <-This is the end value I want 1000x placed in a vector
```

Example Answer of what I want:

```
[1]   0.48 0.42 0.68 0.17 0.2 0.97 0.95 0.53 0.42 0.61 0.64 0.62 0.42 0.40 0.57 0.50
...
...
...
[997] 0.85 0.37 0.40 0.67
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want

```
fun <- function(n1, n2, mu1, mu2, sig1, sig2, reps){
  grp1 <- matrix(rnorm(reps*n1, mu1, sig1), nrow = n1, ncol = reps) # Generate random group 1
  grp2 <- matrix(rnorm(reps*n2, mu2, sig2), nrow = n2, ncol = reps) # Generate random group 2
  pvals <- NULL
  for(i in 1:reps){
    pvals[i] <- t.test(grp1[,i], grp2[,i])$p.value
  }
  pwr <- sum(pvals < 0.05)/reps
  pwr
}

replicate( 1000, fun(20,30,25,32,15,20,100) )
[1] 0.23 0.25 0.34 0.35 0.28 0.24 0.24 0.28 0.27 0.24 0.26 0.32 0.24 0.18 0.20
# etc...
[991] 0.33 0.22 0.36 0.31 0.21 0.27 0.21 0.29 0.29 0.23
```

Comment: Thank you for this! But what I would like to do more or less is add it in the function where I would enter the values in the function argument line (say after the reps value) and make it another loop. So instead of replicating it on the outside of the function, I like to do it in the function. Or have another function call the original function and have it performed there.

Comment: @dnchan19 So in the end you want a vector of 1000 values repeated X times? You could do `replicate( X, replicate( 1000, fun(20,30,25,32,15,20,100) ) )` or `fun2 <- function(x) replicate( x, fun(20,30,25,32,15,20,100) ); replicate( 10, fun2(10) )`